# Qt Animating Window Appearance

Tags: qt, animation, qtquick2

In Qt 5.15 Quick 2 code, setting a `QtQuick.Dialogs` `FileDialog` `visible` property to `true` causes it to animate onto the screen in a "blorping" motion. I am developing a Gantt chart where clicking on an item in the timeline will bring up a window to edit its properties. Is there a way to not just have the Frame/Window appear instantly but instead to "blorp" out of the item clicked like the `FileDialog` does from the top of the window? I notice that the shape and interior controls of the FileDialog are morphed and then solidify to indicate that the dialog is being introduced and which window it is coming from. In my case I hope to have the window pop out of the control it will edit the properties of and, when finished, squirt back inside to reinforce that those properties are being pushed into the item being edited. Is this possible?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Button
    {
        onClicked: chooseFile.visible = true
        text: "Click Me"

    }

    FileDialog
    {
        id: chooseFile

        title: "Save Me!"
        //folder: shortcuts.home
        selectExisting: true



    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Animations when opening windows (in general) can be done with Transition objects.

Comment: @Jarman Yes, thank you. Transitions will certainly be required. What struck me was that a transition on size-only is insufficient because it would resize and perhaps reposition the controls within rather than bend the window and its contents. My gut was that scaling individual controls was unlikely to work due to borders and font sizes, and the entire form and controls _bend_ in the form. Searching for qml widnow "morph",  "bend", or "scale" do not seem to show good results. What is desired here is a morphing "blorp" of the window and contents. Manual rending might work but be inefficient?

Comment: Incidentally, the MacOS Minimize animation is another great example of hardware-accelerated and efficient morphing of a window.

Comment: Right, bending the window over a curve in a 3D way is not a built-in feature that I'm aware of. I'm sure the best way to do it would be to use a ShaderEffect, but I'm not an expert in that area.

Comment: @JarMan Noted. To be clear, to the extend that any 3d effect is present in the examples it is not needed. Animated 2D bending is sufficient.